# Enum é expandido pelo compilador em uma declaração de classe?

Tags: java, classes, enums, compiladores

`Enum` é expandido pelo compilador em uma declaração de classe em Java?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com expandido?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Pode-se entender que um `Enum` é uma classe com características especiais. O compilador sempre tratará esse tipo de forma específica.

- Tem otimizações para alguns cenários como o uso de bits,
- é permitido usar em algumas situações onde a classe não é, por exemplo o `switch`,
- não pode instanciar ou estender o tipo,
- tem serialização e `toString()` automáticos,
- acho que mais algumas coisas.

Então pode-se dizer que sim, pelo menos no final dá mais ou menos na mesma coisa. Não sei se a especificação fala algo sobre como deva ser feito, mas é uma forma possível, até porque desconheço alguma instrução específica no *bytecode* da JVM que trate de enumerações, então tem que ser simulado com alguma outra forma existente e a classe parece adequada.

Há uma [pergunta no SO cujas respostas confirmam isso](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31039980/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O que quer dizer expandido neste caso? Entendi a explicação mas ainda não entendi o que essa pergunta quer saber.

Comment: No que é traduzido depois que compila